# Multi-platform database with parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

When starting a parse app, which SDK do you choose so that an app/website could share the same database between platforms (i.e. share the same usernames and passwords between a website, IOS app, and android app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database can be viewed by any platform. You choose the SDK based on which platform you are developing for. If you're developing for iOS, then you'd use the iOS SDK. If you were making an Android app, then you'd use the Android SDK. Both of these SDKs can point to the same Parse database. You just need to set the correct keys.

Comment: Yep, realized this soon after. Wasn't very familiar with how parse worked at first. Thanks